# How can I use BigQuery's dataset in Data Lab

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have some datasets in BigQuery, I wonder if there is a way to use the same datasets in Data Lab? As the datasets are big, I can't download it and reload it in Data Lab.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BigQuery Python client library support querying data stored in BigQuery. To load the commands from the client library, paste the following code into the first cell of the notebook:

```
%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery
```

`%load_ext` is one of the many Jupyter built-in magic commands.

The BigQuery client library provides a `%%bigquery` cell, which runs a SQL query and returns the results as a Pandas DataFrame.

You can query data from a public dataset or from the datasets in your project:

```
%%bigquery 

SELECT *  

FROM `MY_PROJECT.MY_DATASET.MY_TABLE`  

LIMIT 50
```

I was able to successfully get data from the dataset without any issues.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter). I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tested. Amazing. One thing to remind future readers, it seems working with `python3` only.